# Elasticsearch must with subquery intersection

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I want to perform an Elasticsearch query which combinates two subqueries (AND operator), each one of those subqueries searching in different fields (OR operator).

For example, if I pass the "name" parameter it searches only in name fields (firstname + lastname), if I pass the "contact" parameter it searches in contact fields (ContactEmail + ContactTelephone).

The code below return :

- All results if name is null but contact provided (should only return right part)
- All results if contact is null but name provided (should only return left part)
- union results (OR operator) if name and contact values are provided (should return left intersect right)

```
searchQuery = searchQuery
    .MinScore(minScore)
    .Query(qu => qu
        .Bool(b => b
            .Must(m => m
                .MultiMatch(mm=> mm
                    .Fields(fs=> fs
                        .Field(f => f.Firstname)
                        .Field(f => f.Lastname)
                    )
                    .Query(name)
                    .Operator(Operator.Or)
                )
            )
            .Must(m => m
                .MultiMatch(mm => mm
                    .Fields(fs => fs
                        .Field(f => f.ContactEmail)
                        .Field(f => f.ContactTelephone)
                    )
                    .Query(contact)
                    .Operator(Operator.Or)
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

I am using `Must` because I want the associated score.

I think there are 2 issues: applying AND instead of OR and ignoring subquery if criteria is empty. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two queries in must clauses **must** be part of the same `.Must()` call.

Given the following POCO

```cs
public class Person
{
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public string ContactEmail {get;set;}
    public string ContactTelephone {get;set;}

}
```

The query should look like the following

```cs
var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

var minScore = 2;
string name = "name";
string contact = "contact";

var response = client.Search<Person>(s => s
    .MinScore(minScore)
    .Query(qu => qu
        .Bool(b => b
            .Must(m => m
                .MultiMatch(mm => mm
                    .Fields(fs => fs
                        .Field(f => f.Firstname)
                        .Field(f => f.Lastname)
                    )
                    .Query(name)
                    .Operator(Operator.Or)
                ), m => m
                .MultiMatch(mm => mm
                    .Fields(fs => fs
                        .Field(f => f.ContactEmail)
                        .Field(f => f.ContactTelephone)
                    )
                    .Query(contact)
                    .Operator(Operator.Or)
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

which produces the following

```json
{
  "min_score": 2.0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "fields": [
              "contactEmail",
              "contactTelephone"
            ],
            "operator": "or",
            "query": "contact"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If either `name` or `contact` are `null`, that query will be omitted. For example, setting `name` to `null`

```cs
string name = null;

var response = client.Search<Person>(s => s
    .MinScore(minScore)
    .Query(qu => qu
        .Bool(b => b
            .Must(m => m
                .MultiMatch(mm => mm
                    .Fields(fs => fs
                        .Field(f => f.Firstname)
                        .Field(f => f.Lastname)
                    )
                    .Query(name)
                    .Operator(Operator.Or)
                ), m => m
                .MultiMatch(mm => mm
                    .Fields(fs => fs
                        .Field(f => f.ContactEmail)
                        .Field(f => f.ContactTelephone)
                    )
                    .Query(contact)
                    .Operator(Operator.Or)
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

yields

```json
{
  "min_score": 2.0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "fields": [
              "contactEmail",
              "contactTelephone"
            ],
            "operator": "or",
            "query": "contact"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This takes advantage of a client feature called *conditionless queries* - a specific query is considered to be conditionless if a component of the query is *empty* when it should not be, in order to form a complete query. For example, [for a `multi_match` query, it is considered to be conditionless if the `Query` is `null`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/9929296a9e48868cfc0d701e1bd3bfa6010af3f3/src/Nest/QueryDsl/FullText/MultiMatch/MultiMatchQuery.cs#L215)

[image: MultiMatch query conditionless]

The intention with conditionless queries is that it makes writing more complex queries easier, and [the behaviour can be bypassed by specifying `Verbatim()` on the query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/verbatim-and-strict-query-usage.html). Since they go against the principle of least surprise however, [there is an intention to remove them in the future](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/4050). To perform the same query without relying on conditionless behaviour

```cs
var response = client.Search<Person>(s => s
    .MinScore(minScore)
    .Query(qu => qu
        .Bool(b => b
            .Must(m =>
                {
                    if (name == null)
                        return m;
                        
                    return m
                        .MultiMatch(mm => mm
                            .Fields(fs => fs
                                .Field(f => f.Firstname)
                                .Field(f => f.Lastname)
                            )
                            .Query(name)
                            .Operator(Operator.Or)
                        );
                }, m => 
                {
                    if (contact == null)
                        return m;

                    return m
                        .MultiMatch(mm => mm
                            .Fields(fs => fs
                                .Field(f => f.ContactEmail)
                                .Field(f => f.ContactTelephone)
                            )
                            .Query(contact)
                            .Operator(Operator.Or)
                        );
                }
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Thank you @Russ Cam for such a high quality answer!

Comment: No worries! Hope it helps